# How to do transaction using aws s3 in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I wrote image upload method using spring boot of java as below.
It saves title and image path etc before upload image called Todo class.

```
@Override
public Todo saveTodo(String title, String description, MultipartFile file) {
    // check if the file is empty
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot upload empty file");
    }
    // Check if the file is an image
    if (!Arrays.asList(IMAGE_PNG.getMimeType(), IMAGE_BMP.getMimeType(), IMAGE_GIF.getMimeType(),
            IMAGE_JPEG.getMimeType()).contains(file.getContentType())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("FIle uploaded is not an image");
    }
    // get file metadata
    Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    metadata.put("Content-Type", file.getContentType());
    metadata.put("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.getSize()));
    // Save Image in S3 and then save Todo in the database
    String path = String.format("%s/%s", amazonConfig.getBucketName(), UUID.randomUUID());
    String fileName = String.format("%s", file.getOriginalFilename());

    Todo todo = Todo.builder().description(description).title(title).imagePath(path).imageFileName(fileName)
            .build();
    repository.save(todo);

    try {
        fileStore.upload(path, fileName, Optional.of(metadata), file.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to upload file", e);
    }

    return repository.findByTitle(todo.getTitle());
}
```

But when the error occurs doing upload , I want to delete the inserted todo totally.
I can delete using repository delete method in catch manually.
But Can I do this action without delete method writing only @transacion or something? 
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: How do you know that if an IOException has occured, that the file was not indeed uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just annotate the `saveTodo` method with `@Transactional`.

Itt will look like something this:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

// other imports
// other code 

@Override
@Transactional
public Todo saveTodo(....
```

Then it will rollback if a RuntimeException occurs. (IllegalStateException is a RuntimeException, so it will work fine)